# how to remove index.php?file= using .htaccess to get last url

Tags: php, .htaccess

Here, I want to remove index.php?file= for every urls of my website. I have tried many tutorial of .htaccess,but unlucky to create correct one. 
Actual url as below:

```
http://localhost/test/json/iscore2/index.php?file=home
http://localhost/test/json/iscore2/index.php?file=contact
```

Then I want to make like this :

```
http://localhost/test/json/iscore2/home
http://localhost/test/json/iscore2/contact
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you already have setted up rewrite module in apache2
(`sudo a2enmod rewrite` and host settings for `AllowOverride`)

I'd start with something like this in `iscore2` folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on

    # Play with this if redirection fails
    #RewriteBase /

    # if it is not a file or folder, rewrite to index.php?file=<value>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?file=$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: thank @muka, but  how to implement the script ?because I have created .htaccess in iscore2 folder and copy your script inside,It's still not working.

Comment: oh,your script is working fine,it's my fault that not change the url before run the website. :D